# Is there a React SSR alternative to amp-live-list?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

We have an SSR website running on React and Node. We are currently using **amp-live-list** to keep our liveblogs updated.

Are there any alternatives to amp-live-list already out there that don't use the amp framework?

There is currently a process to use **Hydration** with fetch calls to update this list for a non-amp implementation.